# How to go about caching promises when working with the new fetch API?

Tags: javascript, caching, promise, race-condition, fetch-api

Sometimes you want to use the same promised object in multiple times and places. Such as a promise for an AJAX resource from a URL.

It's difficult to cache the object because you don't know when it will asynchronously be avaible.

That's OK because you can [call `.then()` multiple times on a single promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise#then()) so you cache it the first time you need it and access the cache the subsequent times. And when it's available all the `.then`s will be carried out.

But when the promise is from [the new fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) it doesn't appear to be so straightforward... because a second promise is involved.

`fetch()` itself returns a promise and when it's fulfilled you must access the HTTP response's body via a second promise using a method such as [`.blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) or [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). These are part of the ["Body mixin"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body).

Vanilla example of how to use `fetch()`:

```
fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
  return resp.json().then(function(json) {
    // use the JSON
  });
});
```

The problems is that even though you can call `.then()` multiple times you **can't** call the functions such as `.blob()` and `.json()` multiple times on a single response.

It seems then that the result of `.json()` etc would also need to be cached, but that ought to be more difficult since it will only be available asynchronously. The resource could be requested twice before the two asynch promises resolve - a race condition.

Am I missing something? Is there an easy way to cache fetch's promise's JSON etc than I can't see? I can't seem to find this discussed on the net anywhere.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a variable to store that?

Comment: Where and when would the variable go to be accessible considering the asynchronicity?

Comment: It is unclear the scope in which you need to use this variable. Inside your then block after the fetch call, you could define a variable above the return statement and assign it in the first then block of said return statement. Then a subsequent return statement inside the the same fetch block could access the contents of that variable. But once again, your question was unclear as to when those cache results need to be accessed. If it's beyond the fetch request and any subsequent chaining, then please specify so.

Comment: Well my real code is convoluted involving at least two loops of asynchronous fetch calls to retrieve values that will then be filtered and cross referenced against each other. That's why I was wanting to store values in a cache. Of course one could consider a cache object to be a variable. But one loop will be writing to it and another will be reading from it and both asynchronous. My question attempts to address the general problem rather than code review my specific project (-:

Comment: I think you might get a better answer if you explained exactly what you want to happen. 2 loops of asynchronous fetch calls? Are these 2 loops running in parallel? And when is the filtering and the 'cross referencing' happening? More details would really help. The only thing I can gather from your problem right now might be that you want to use Promise.all and wait for both loops to be done and then do your filtering/cross referencing synchronously but again what you are trying to accomplish seems very vague.

Comment: It's tricky to explain. To me it was just a typical case of caching. I just found it hard because things are asynch and I'm using new ES6 stuff. You can see [my current test code](https://tonicdev.com/hippietrail/5762df1363d60f130066bb80) if you really need specifics. I've solved the problem now and will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an updated and **much more concise** solution now that I understand promises a bit better. I didn't fully grok chaining via `.then()` after all and I realized my previous solution actually used ["The Deferred anti-pattern"](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) aka http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

```js
let cache = {};

function cachingFetchJSON(url) {
  if (!cache.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
    console.log('fetching from afar');
    cache[url] = fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json());
  } else {
    console.log('fetching from cache');
  }
  return cache[url];
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  cachingFetchJSON("//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1))
    .then(val => console.log(val))
    .catch(c => console.error('caught', c));
}
```

And here's the original solution I came up with after posting this question and learning from all the answers and comments:

Rather than just cache the promises returned as part of the `fetch()` API I create a new promise which is resolved only with the JSON text retrieved from the response body.

```js
function fetchJSON(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('fetching from afar');
    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json()
        .then(json => resolve(json)))
      .catch(reason => reject(reason));
  });
}

let cache = {};

function cachingFetchJSON(url) {
  if (!cache.hasOwnProperty(url))
    cache[url] = fetchJSON(url);
  else
    console.log('fetching from cache');
  return cache[url];
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  cachingFetchJSON("//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1))
    .then(val => console.log(val))
    .catch(c => console.error('caught', c));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not call `.json()` or `.text()` multiple times on a response because any of these methods consumes the body but you can copy the response before using it so you can simply cache the promise but instead of doing:

```
cachedFetch.then(response => response.json()).then(console.log);
```

Do:

```
cachedFetch.then(response => response.clone().json()).then(console.log);
```

Or wrap your `fetch` call inside a function that always returns a respone clone:

```
doFetch().then(response => response.json()).then(console.log);
```

Where:

```
var _cached;
function doFetch() {
  if (!_cached) {
    _cached = fetch('/something');
  }
  return _cached.then(r => r.clone());
}
```

Comment: Actually I did notice this `.clone()` method but I assumed that would result in unnecessary resource usage so didn't investigate further.

Comment: Also, should all of your examples be using `cachedFetch()` or should should the first two be using `fetch()`? Should the final one be recursive? I'm not sure if you've made a typo or I'm not understanding something.

Comment: Nop. In the first example I assume you madre your `fetch()` calle elsewhere and you put the returned promise in `cachedFetch`. In the last example the función does everything in placer. Anyway, I changed the answer to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with es6 promise, however here is the basics how i do it in angularJS which is the same conceptually.

Instead of returning the promise given by fetch. You use a crafted one, this gives you the power to resolve it when you want :

- Immediately if it's in the cache
- When the server response is ready and parsed.

Here is how i handle caching in angluar's promise

```
var cache = [..]//fetching cache from somewhere using an API 
var deferred = $q.defer();//build an empty promise;
if(cache.contains('myKey')){
    var data = cache.get('myKey');
    // wrap data in promise
    deferred.resolve(data);
}else{
     fetch(req).then(function(resp) {
         resp.json().then(function(json) {
             cache.put('myKey', json);
             deferred.resolve(json);//resolve promise
         });
     });
 }
 return deferred.promise;//return the promise object on which you will be able to call `then`
```

Since es6 promise are really close of angular's one you should be able to adapt your code to fit.

Comment: Exactly, maybe even the cache if you retrieve it from some 3rd party library ofrlocalStorage that manage the cache for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Salva answer, I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kvangrae/3ecccff6b21af60009e448457b6a8179) that uses [lodash.memoize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.memoize) and `response.clone()`.

```
import memoize from 'lodash.memoize';

const cache = memoize(req => {
    return fetch(req).then(response => {
        return response;
    });
}, req => req.url);

function cacheFetch(input, init) {
    return cache(new Request(input, init)).then(response => response.clone());
}

export default cacheFetch;
```